# What is the reason behind this Error?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb6-migration

I have faced a problem when converting the access .mdb file data to CSV.I got this error **"The command or action 'TransferText' isn't available now"** when doing the transferText with the inbuild function.

The code was written like this

```
Access_Application_definst.DoCmd.TransferText(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcTextTransferType.acExportDelim, , "employee", <FileName>, True)
```

May I know the reason behind this error ? Already TransferText is a inbuilt function?

Comment: Is <FileName> a directory for which you have permissions? Is it open? Does it have a permitted extension?

Comment: If employee is a query, does it run? Does someone else have the database open? For me, the above code works, modified for my set-up.

Comment: The File name include the directory path also.The DB is not opened.